# Not able to print the values from my node in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Firebase structure looks like this

```
characters
     -Lt9nfslaIKgoe7E3SHT
     -LtA93jCQn-2Kmf4gP-S
     -LtK-Bk156abpROmhxgI
     ... 
          in these keys booleans are saved from 1 - 64, true or false
          1: true,
          2: true,
          3: false,
          ...
```

I want to log the array values of each key

```
char_ref = db.reference('characters/{}' + str.format(char_key_array[3]))
```

returns firebase_admin.db.Reference object at 0x74dfb970

```
char_snapshot = char_ref.get()
```

returns none

Anybody has a clue why char_snapshot = char_ref.get() returns none?

Comment: My best bet is that your `char_ref` is not referring to a location in the database where you have the actual value you're looking for. It's hard to say why, given that `{}` seems unusual in your path, and we have no way to know what `char_key_array[3]` is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error. You probably meant `'characters/{}'.format(char_key_array[3])`